# Telerik RadUpload control error

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radupload

I am using Telerik RadUpload control for uploading images but on localhost or on local machine its work but when I transfer these code to my hosting panel and then I am try to do same its not working. you can check the [error at this site.](http://www.gts24x7.in/upload.aspx)

So help me to come out from this error.

[image]

Comment: I am not getting how to solve this problem

Comment: SO is not a live support from telerik. If you are in hurry, call telerik +1-888-365-2779.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register RadUploadProgressHandler in web.config. Here is the [instruction](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/upload-configuration.html).

Comment: I do that but now I am getting a error window that you can check at www.gts24x7.in/upload.aspx

Comment: It's a different error. You still need write permission to your folder http://www.banmanpro.com/support2/permissions.asp